# Adding thickness to a mesh in Blender

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm using blender to make a basic model of my house and I want to hollow out the inside of the house so that the walls are slightly thicker and there are normals facing both ways, I'm not really sure how to can achieve this. I think it's called shelling?

[image]

Also, has anyone got any tips on working on the interior of buildings, because I find it nearly impossible to do so :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [*Solidify* modifier could be useful here. Go and check it out](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html).

If you want to do buildings I would highly recommend that you "build" the house, instead of trying to carve it out of a block.

It would be a lot easier to build everything in pieces. Not everything has to be done in one piece in Blender. And you can always merge the Geometry later.

Build walls, cut windows into them. Add the window frames. Etc.

Build the house, dont try and carve it out.

Comment: So build the inside outside and then simply drag it in?

Comment: Yeah you can do it like that. Think less Inside-Outside and more building a "Movie Stage". Fake walls and props. And instead of putting things inside. Assemble a room, and put the walls around it after :)

Comment: Playing around with Valve Hammer gave me some insights when I used it

Comment: Or better still: Start out by drawing your floor plan onto a plane, then grab all the edges and extrude the walls up all at the same time.

Comment: There is also a pretty good addon that aids in making architectural elements, walls, doors, windows, roofs, etc. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Archimesh