# extrude, intersect, slice complex shapes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a 3D dragon (from Spyro 1) that I want to transform into a glass decoration for my home.

Before proceeding, i need to eliminate the 3mm thickness from every face, obtaining a shape that can be used to properly cut the glass pieces.

This could be useful to every artist who wants to do Tiffany glass works.

It's been two days I've been trying day and night, and still not found a good way to obtain what i need.

First, i separated every face of the model. 
*Mesh > Edges > Mark Sharp*, *Edge Split* modifier, split angle 0°, sharp edges checked. In edit mode, select all, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> scale planes by -0,03, (because the glass I am going to use is 3mm thick)

When the angle between faces is bigger than or equal to 180° it's OK. The scaled faces don't overlap, and they will be printed and cut as they are, but if the angle is smaller than or or equal to 180°, then the planes will intersect, and here comes the problem.

[image: ugly example of the angles thing]

I have 160 different faces to intersect, and I am trying to do the job manually. It's a hard work, and Booleans do what they want. I am going crazy with them.

I have tried a second alternative, I extruded every face (vertex normals, -0.03), turn them into separate objects, then I used Booleans to subtract their shape from the dragon (it was like peeling an orange), but Booleans agreed to do it only on 90 of the 160 objects. Rage and frustration.

Should I insist with Boolean operations and extruded faces? Is there some magic that allows to do batch Boolean operations, or is there some trick or command that I don't know? (I am a total newbie)

I've prepared a file with the head of the dragon and two examples one for the scaling method, one for the Boolean method

[drago di cristallo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj1pklk4cpyyx3i/drago%20di%20cristallo%20esempio.blend?dl=0)

I hope my explanation is clear enough.   :P

Comment: Hi, I check your .blend and have no good info for you. All I can write is: you doing it wrong from beginning. For 3D print you need one solid object, without nonmanifold edges and vertices. After than you can use solidify modifier for make "wall". BTW: scale 0.03 dies not mean 3mm. Its ratio/relative size. It is not dimension.

Comment: @Shubol3D - please read carefully. He doesn't want to print out a 3D model. He wants to do it in a Tiffany like artstyle.

Comment: @Davide, I assume that "3 drago untouched" is the result you are aiming for? The overall bad news is that Blender is not intended to do precision work. Its primary focus is and always will be that of a 3D modeling and rendering tool. So that's the first hurdle to take.

Comment: @ metaphor_set drago untouched is the original starting shape

Comment: this is the result i am aiming for  http://i65.tinypic.com/zo6sf6.jpg.
A smaller shape wich faces are at the same distance from the original ones (but on a 3D object). 
I guess the best way could be "slicing" the faces with the booleans as in the exemple file...

Comment: So do you want to add a thickness to the drago's mesh ? Kind of duplicating the model and scaling it a bit down so they are of the same shape but of different size ?

Comment: @ metaphor_set: yes, you are right. I'm sorry. I have no idea why I thing he wants to 3D print this.

Comment: @Mr zak  i added thickness (going to the inside, not making the object bigger. that's why i used -0.03 instead of 0.03) to the faces in order to substract it from the whole model and obtain the internal shape.
the thickness should simulate the 3mm glass layer, someway.

Comment: Like here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/adding-thickness-to-a-mesh-in-blender ?

Comment: @Davide, is this by any chance the result you are looking for? http://imgur.com/a/GuxG8

Comment: Mr Zak i've seen that yesterday, when looking info about the command solidify. i think i have to learn more about it, because it needs a chance. in fact, that command makes extrusions perpendicular to the faces.

metaphor_set no i am sorry. i need the inner faces resulting from the shrinking of the outer layer...
im trying to figure out with solidify. effectively it can do the trick, but some parts of the mesh become a mess.
look, it's the inner faces i need to extract  http://i68.tinypic.com/ff4prr.jpg
i need to learn more about that command and the parameters

Comment: but new vertex form for no reason, and some faces emerge from the inside http://i65.tinypic.com/2ivo10x.jpg

Comment: @Shubol3D, unclear... I share your opinion that is it for a 3D print, because of "glass decoration for my home" and "can be used to properly cut the glass pieces". But we may be wrong. I understand the question as "I want to use this model, 3D printed, in order to have a template to cut real glass parts". Davide, could you confirm ?

Comment: YES!!!
template, that's the word! i want to make a template. i wish i remembered this word yesterday...
but no, not 3d printed.  i want the shape of the internal surface, and i will print the faces on paper, and i will use them as template

Comment: ok, so what you want to do is to have the faces of the dragon (minus the 3mm) but made printable on a paper. On this paper these faces will be printed flat (as if each face was on the floor). So that all this allows you to cut the glass, using the faces on the paper as templates. That's it ?

Comment: If yes, simply use one of the methods given in the answers below, then go to edit mode, select all, use the "U" key, choose "unwrap". You will have it on the image editor and you can print it using the "UV" menu then "export UV layout" **have a try on a carton before cutting the glass**

Answer (score 1):

I think that the solution to this is Blender's inset function. The goal is to separate all faces equidistantly from another and do this in an efficient way.

Please be aware of the fact, that Blender is not intended to be a precision CAD software. The primary use is and always will be 3D modeling and rendering.

In the first step we need to change the unit settings to the Units we want to take our measures in (Properties Window - Scene Panel). In this example this will be "Metric", "Degrees" and a conversion scale of 1.0

[image: Units]

We also want to apply the scale of the object to ensure that the values will be applied in the right scale. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select "Scale.

[image]

This is how your object's Transform values should change.

The next step is to separate the faces from each other. Tab into Edit Mode, type <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces, hit <kbd>Space</kbd>, type "Edge Split" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Now that we have separated faces in our mesh we can inset them. Blender is not capable to do this in one step but the method we are going to use is still fairly easy.

If something else is selected, switch to "Face Select", type <kbd>A</kbd> to select all Faces, then <kbd>I</kbd> to start Face inset. Use the mouse to resize the inset value to approximately the desired size. If the gap's size between the faces should be 3mm go to the operator panel and set "Thickness" to 1.5mm (type in both the value and the unit here). **Do not select or deselect any faces after that!**

[image: inset faces]

The last step is to delete the newly created redundant faces. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection, hit <kbd>X</kbd> to delete and choose "Faces".

[image: delete redundant faces]

As a result you should get a model which is made out of separated and evenly spaced faces.

[image: result]

The described method works also on ngons.

[image: inset ngons]

To get a cutting pattern for your Tiffany work, you could uv-unwrap your model, increase the margin width between the islands and export it as svg. With inkscape you would be able to resize the pattern and move the pieces around until you get something useful.

Comment: make a gap on the edges....this could be the perfect solution if there is some way to make the gap between pieces proportional to the angle, instead of equal everywhere.

I think something like that needs to be scripted as a new addon. 

In fact,if the angle (measured on the inside) between two faces is 180 or greater, the gap will be 0.  If the angle between faces is 90, the gap will be equal to the given thickness.

Comment: When 2 faces form a right angle (measured on the inside of the object) it can be calculated easily.

We have the given thickness, wich is leg b.
We have the right angle
We have the angle between the 2 edges (wich we divide by 2) .

We only need to find the leg a, wich will be the gap size.

Comment: tan (angle)= adjacent leg\opposite leg.
After substituting β=45° and b=3  we have tan (45°)= 3\a.  
a=3\tan (45°).  
a=3\1.  
a=3  

In this case, the gap will be 3 (same as the thickness). 
Obviously, when the (internal) angle is equal or bigger than 180°, there will be no gap and the calculation will be skipped.
The next step is to find someone who can script this sorcery.

https://s32.postimg.org/gtcts29ol/calculate.jpg

Comment: i mean, some script that create a duplicate of the faces, cutting away the gaped edge from every face. i hope my english is good enough...

Answer (score 0):

First apply the scale to your object so dimensions are correct.

[image: Apply scale]

Add a *Solidify* modifier to you mesh with a $0.03$ thickness, so that you can obtain an inner offset of your surface 3 mm apart to the inside.

Apply the *Solidify* modifier, enter edit mode and select all the outer shell of your mesh by hovering one of its vertex and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>.

[image: Shell]

Erase the outer shell, mark all edges sharp, add an *Edgesplit* modifier and apply it so all faces are now independent.

Enter edit mode again, select all remaining faces from the inner shell and use the *Inset* operator to inset all faces $0.03$ units.

Tick the *Select Outer* option so all borders are selected and erase them.

[image: Inset]

You should now have a fully offset mesh by $0.03$ units inside, and all faces offset $0.03$ units from their individual borders.

Have in mind that with current object dimensions, an offset of 3 mm in almost totally erase certain faces, especially in sharp or very narrow areas like the tips of the ears/horns.

[image: Final]